# Using a token list in tabularray

Tags: tables, expl3, tabularray

I am trying to expand `\mydataX` a `tblr` environment that contains a `tl` variable, and getting the following error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. \__tl_if_novalue:w #1-NoValue-#2?#3?!->`. I don't have an issue executing the same code in a `tabular` environment. Furthermore, using `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` generates an infinite loop in the `tblr` environment. I would appreciate any assistance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:cn {l_tmpa_tl}{1 & 2 & 3}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mydata}{O{,}m}{#2#1~1 & 2 & 3}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mydataX}{O{,}m}{#2#1~\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines, colspec={QQQ}}
    \expanded{\mydata[,]{Data}}  \\
    \expanded{\mydataX[,]{Data}} \\ % Not working!
\end{tblr}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \mydata[,]{Data}  \\
    \mydataX[,]{Data} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use `\l_tmpa_tl` to store your data. Temporary variables can be used by everyone and so you should use them only if you are sure that nobody changes them inbetween your definition and the use.

In this case if you add `\tracingassigns=1` before the `tblr` you will see in the log:

```
{changing \l_tmpa_tl=macro:->1&2&3}
{into \l_tmpa_tl=macro:->\expanded {\mydata [,]{Data}} \ETC.}
```

and then your code explodes ... Use some other variable name. Btw: `\tl_use:N` is not needed.

Comment: That said: packages shouldn't be using the generic scratch vars either

Comment: @JosephWright, In your opinion, when should we use the scratch variables?